# Master mind number postition value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a Master Mind program where the user should guess a 4 digit number, where all of the digits have to be different. If a digit in the user´s guess is in the number but not on the right position it is shown with a "F", and if it is on the right position it is shown with a "R". The problem with my code is that if the user´s guess contain 2 or more of the same digit and the first one is on the wrong place but the second one is on the right place it shows a "F" but it should show a "R". could you please help me find a way to fix this.

```
value = ""
tmp = [False]*4 
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        if userAnswer[i] == computerNumber[j]:
            if i==j and tmp[j]!= True:
                tmp[j] = True 
                value += "R"
            elif tmp[j] != True:
                tmp[j] = True
                value += "F"
            break
return value
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
def guess(user_answer, true_number):
    right_position = [(user_answer[i] == true_number[i]) for i in range(4)]
    right_number = [(not right_position[i] and (user_answer[i] in true_number)) for i in range(4)]
    return 'R' * right_position.count(True) + 'F' * right_number.count(True)
```

**EDITED:** I was not quite sure exactly what output do you need. If you want there be only 'R' (no 'F's) when there is any exact match, you may find this working:

```
def guess(user_answer, true_number):
    right_position = [(user_answer[i] == true_number[i]) for i in range(4)]
    if any(right_position):
        return 'R' * right_position.count(True)
    right_number = [(user_answer[i] in true_number) for i in range(4)]
    if any(right_number):
        return 'F' * right_number.count(True)
    return '' # or what else you want to indicate that there's no matching
```

**AGAIN EDITED:** This time I think I shall have got you idea. :) Then this shall work as you expect:

```
def guess(user_answer, true_number):
    right_position = [(user_answer[i] == true_number[i]) for i in range(4)]
    if any(right_position):
        return 'R'
    right_number = [(user_answer[i] in true_number) for i in range(4)]
    if any(right_number):
        return 'F'
    return '' # or what else you want to indicate that there's no matching
```

Comment: The problem now is that this function returns both "F" and "R" for the same number. For example if the user_answer is 4444 and true_number is 1234 the function returns "RFFF" when it is only supposed to return "R"

Comment: @user3139496 Well I'm actually not very sure about what output do you want.. Shall it be only 'R' (no 'F's) when there is an exact match? I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: The problem is that a digit in the number should only return "F" or "R". If user_answer is "4456" and true_number is "1234" the functions should return "F" and not "FF" and if user_answer is "5226" and true_number is "1234" the function should return "R", not "RF". Yes, it should only be "R"s when it is a exact match.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use a good slicing structure instead so many nested statements. 
The below link and code shows a good approach.

choice (the players 4 number input)
and makeRandomeWhenGameStarts() (this is the random 4 number to guess)

what happens in the code is that it takes the numbers from 
1234 and 1423 and turns them into strings:

```
  playGuess= [['1'],['2'], ['3'],['4']]

  ranRoll= [['1'],['3'],['4'],['2']]


  #then you want to do 2 things
  #see if i in guess is in randomroll and count them for whitepegs
  #Then see what is in the same position: 

  nWhitePegs = len([i for i in playGuess if i in ranRoll])
  then see how many are in the same postion
  nRedPegs   = sum([1 if i==j else 0 for i, j in zip(playGuess,ranRoll)])
```

AHA! alas we gave them a white for all the reds, but dont worry its ok we just do some math and "-" minus 1 white for every red
Tada keep it simple, keep it beautiful.

Please see this answer already provided at the link below:

If you look within the while loop you should be able to use this code.

[Mastermind Python Using "ABCDEF"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380893/mastermind-python-using-abcdef/45758114#45758114)