# Mastermind Python Using "ABCDEF"

Tags: python-3.x

Mastermind Game using "ABCEF"I dont know how to check whether it is partial correct. I have to use red to mean correct letter and position. I use white to mean correct letter.

```
import random

def play_one_round():
    N_code=''.join(random.sample("ABCDEF",4))
    print (N_code)
    guess=input("Enter your guess as 4 letters e.g. XXXX:")
    count_guess= 1
    while N_code != guess and count_guess < 10:
          check(N_code,guess)
          guess=input("Enter your guess as 4 letters e.g. XXXX:")
          count_guess=count_guess + 1
          print("This is your",count_guess, "guess")
          if guess==N_code:
             print('r') #Here I have if the code and guess are equal print r, which mean its the right letters in the right order.

def check(N_code,guess):
result=['r' if c1==c2 else c2 for c1,c2 in zip(guess, N_code)]
     for index, char in enumerate(guess):
         if result[index] !='r':
             if char in result:
                result[result.index(char)]='w'

 print(result)

def Master_m():
    print("Welcome to Mastermind!\n")
    print("Start by Choosing four letters")
    play_one_round()
    answer=input("Play Again? ")
    if answer[0]=='y':
       Master_m()

Master_m()
```

Comment: Your code has indentation problems. It seems that you haven't put everything in a code block and with some lines such as `guess=...` its not clear if it should be in a fuction or not. Fix those and we can read it more easily.

Comment: oh, and tell us what went wrong and what you'd like to see so we don't have  to guess.

Comment: I'm new to stack flow, I don't know how to format it, to show correctly. I am actually stuck. I'm new to this and we have to create a game using the Alphabets. This  is how far I've gotten, how do I count partial correct 
 answer but also the correct position, I also have to tell the user that, using the red and white pegs. Red meaning its the right letters and in the correct position(order) and white meaning it is the correct letter.

Comment: I edited your code for the indentations I think you wanted. Check it out and fix what you need to.

Comment: Now that the indentation is fixed, what is my next step. My instructor said to use a transversal with a for loop and the in operator. But I m not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this ages ago but it will do the trick

```
    import random
    import itertools

    def start():
        """ this function is used to initialise the users interaction with the game 
        Primarily this functions allows the user to see the rules of the game or play the game"""
        print ('Mastermind, what would you like to do now?\n')
        print ('Type 1 for rules')
        print ('Type 2 to play')
        path = input('Type your selection 1 or 2: ')
        if path == '1':
            print ('Great lets look at the rules')
            rules()
        elif path == '2':
            print('Great lets play some Mastermind!\n')
            begingame()
            start()
        else:
            print('that was not a valid response there is only one hidden option that is not a 1 or a 2')
            start()  

    def rules():
        """This just prints out the rules to the user."""
        print ('The rules are as follows:\n')
        print ('1)Mastermind will craft you a 4 digit number that will contain all unique numbers from 1-9, there is no 0s.\n')
        print ('2)You will have 12 attempts to guess the correct number.\n')
        print ('3)Whites represent a correct number that is not in the correct order\n')
        print ('4)Reds represent a correct number in the correct order.\n')
        print ('5)If you enter a single number or the same number during a guess it will consume 1 of your 12 guesses.\n')
        print ('6)to WIN you must guess the 4 numbers in the correct order.\n')
        print ('7)If you run out of guesses the game will end and you lose.\n')
        print ('8)if you make a guess that has letters or more than 4 digits you will lose a turn.')
        start()

    def makeRandomWhenGameStarts():
        """A random 4 digit number is required this is created as its own 
        variable that can be passed in at the start of the game, this allows the user 
        to guess multiple times against the one number."""

        #generate a 4 digit number 
        num = random.sample(range(1,9), 4)

        #roll is the random 4 digit number as an int supplied to the other functions
        roll = int(''.join(map(str,num)))

        return roll

    def begingame():
        """This is the main game function. primarily using the while loop, the makeRandomWhenGameStarts variable is 
        passed in anbd then an exception handling text input is used to ask the user for their guees """
        print ('please select 4 numbers')

        #bring in the random generated number for the user to guess. 
        roll                = makeRandomWhenGameStarts()
        whiteResults        = []
        redResults          = []
        collectScore        = []
        guessNo             = 0

        #setup the while loop to end eventually with 12 guesses finishing on the 0th guess. 
        guesses = 12
        while (guesses > 0 ):
            guessNo = guessNo + 1
            try:
                #choice = int(2468) #int(input("4 digit number"))
                choice = int(input("Please try a 4 digit number: "))
                if not (1000 <= choice <= 9999):
                    raise ValueError()
                    pass
            except ValueError:
                print('That was not a valid number, you lost a turn anyway!')
                pass
            else:
                print ( "Your choice is", choice)

            #Use for loops to transform the random number and player guess into lists
            SliceChoice = [int(x) for x in str(choice)]
            ranRoll     = [int(x) for x in str(roll)]

            #Take the individual digits and assign them a variable as an identifier of what order they exist in.
            d1Guess = SliceChoice[0:1]
            d2Guess = SliceChoice[1:2]
            d3Guess = SliceChoice[2:3]
            d4Guess = SliceChoice[3:4]

            #combine the sliced elements into a list
            playGuess = (d1Guess+d2Guess+d3Guess+d4Guess)

            #Set reds and whites to zero for while loop turns       
            nRed   = 0
            nWhite = 0  

            #For debugging use these print statements to compare the guess from the random roll
            # print(playGuess, 'player guess')
            # print(ranRoll,'random roll')

            #Use for loops to count the white pegs and red pegs 
            nWhitePegs = len([i for i in playGuess if i in ranRoll])
            nRedPegs   = sum([1 if i==j else 0 for i, j in zip(playGuess,ranRoll)])


            print ('Oh Mastermind that was a good try! ')

            #Take the results of redpegs and package as turnResultsRed
            TurnResultsRed = (nRedPegs)

            #Take the results of whitepegs and remove duplication (-RedPegs) package as TurnResultsWhite 
            TurnResultsWhite = ( nWhitePegs - nRedPegs) #nWhite-nRed 

            #Create a unified list with the first element being the guess number 
            # using guessNo as an index and storing the players choice and results to feedback at the end 
            totalResults = ( guessNo,choice , TurnResultsWhite ,TurnResultsRed)

            # collectScore = collectScore + totalResults for each turn build a list of results for the 12 guesses
            collectScore.append(totalResults)

            #End the while loop if the player has success with 4 reds       
            if nRed == (4):
                print('Congratulations you are a Mastermind!')
                break       

            #Return the results of the guess to the user
            print ('You got:',TurnResultsWhite,'Whites and',TurnResultsRed,'Red\n')

            #remove 1 value from guesses so the guess counter "counts down" 
            guesses = guesses -1
            print ('You have', guesses, "guesses left!")

        #First action outside the while loop tell the player the answer and advise them Game Over
        print('Game Over!')
        print('The answer was', roll)

        #At the end of the game give the player back their results as a list
        for x in collectScore:
            print ('Guess',x[0],'was',x[1],':','you got', x[2],'Red','and', x[3],'Whites')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        start()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are stuck, decompose into smaller chunks and test those. Focusing on `check`, you can check whether a guess letter exactly matches the code via its index and whether its in the code at all with `in`. Here is a self-contained example. Notice that I've pulled out everything except the problem at hand.

If this works for you, I suggest writing a self-contained example of your next problem, test it, and if you are still stuck, post that as a new question.

```
def check(N_code, guess):
    print('code', N_code, 'guess', guess)
    result = []
    # enumerate gives you each letter and its index from 0
    for index, letter in enumerate(guess):
        if N_code[index] == letter:
            # right letter in right position
            vote = 'red'
        elif letter in N_code:
            # well, at least the letter is in the code
            vote = 'white'
        else:
            # not even close
            vote = 'black'
        # add partial result
        result.append('{} {}'.format(letter, vote))
    # combine and print
    print(', '.join(result))

check('ABCD', 'ABCD')
check('DEFA', 'ABCD')
```

Comment: I Updated my answer, but still have a problem, I think it is because of the "zip". I need an x to show up for the wrong letter.